# NodeJs & BigQuery integration error: "Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to use [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery), however, when I run the script I get the error `Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.`

This is the full code following the tutorial:

```js
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

async function queryStackOverflow() {
  const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();

  const sqlQuery = `SELECT
    CONCAT(
      'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
      CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
    view_count
    FROM \`bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions\`
    WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
    ORDER BY view_count DESC
    LIMIT 10`;

  const options = {
    query: sqlQuery,
    location: 'US',
  };

  const [rows] = await bigqueryClient.query(options);

  console.log('Query Results:');
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const url = row['url'];
    const viewCount = row['view_count'];
    console.log(`url: ${url}, ${viewCount} views`);
  });
}

queryStackOverflow();
```

**EDIT:**

I wonder if I should create a project through BigQuery's UI & import the `StackOverflow`'s dataset so the script can recognize the project's ID?

**EDIT2:**

I created a project & add the public dataset for StackOverflow, the logged through the Google CLI & still get the same error. Investing further...

Comment: Did you add public dataset to your BigQuery?

Comment: I just follow the article shared in my question so I assume it's a no. Do you have any docs I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue with the error by following the documentation on authorization [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started). I needed to log in to Google CLI. Then, create & download a `json` containing the credentials & set the env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the `json`'s path.